Routing Configuration for Multihomed Device
I have an issue with a multihomed device, which has to fulfill some specific requirements. I try to describe this question as neutral as possible and not to go into details of possible solutions up front. Although I have some ideas, none of them solves all the cases described below.
The device runs a custom embedded Linux with kernel 5.1.x and has up to three network connections at the same time.

eth0 (wired ethernet)
mlan0 (WiFi)
mobile1 (LTE modem)

Each active connection will be provided with a default gateway by the DHCP server or mobile provider.
Issue 1: Internet Connection

If eth0 has internet access, it must be preferred over mlan0 and mobile1 for internet access.
If mlan0 has internet access, it must  be preferred over mobile1.
If neither eth0 nor mlan0 have internet access, use mobile1.
If one internet connection fails, the next one has to be used.
If one Internet connection comes back up and is more preferred than the currently active one, the reestablished connection has to be used.

What is the best way to configure the routing to work like this?
Issue 2: DNS and Connectivity over specific interfaces

In some scenarios, a private network is reachable over the LTE connection, but no internet. So an internet connection has to be used over ethernet or WiFi.
We have to check the DNS server of the LTE connection and if it does not know a host, we have to proceed with the DNS server of another interface.
In this scenario, we have to use the LTE connection for anything, that is reachable there, but because of host name and IP address overlapping, we cannot know before trying, if the request is for the public internet or the private network over mobile broadband.

I am quite sure, I am not alone with this kind of "try this network and if it fails, use the other one" scenario, but after several hours of research I still cannot get my head around a solution that solves it.
Has anyone a solution or a good suggestion for solving this two issues?

You have to check all the routes periodically and install the appropriate default route, according to whatever logic you can imagine. Do it yourself. Write a script and run it via cron, or write a daemon, it's up to you. Or find a ready-made one. Linux won't do it for you.
Linux has no way to automatically select route based on reachability. It doesn't watch the reachability of the default gateway or any other gateway in the system. The most automation it can do for you is if the NIC is down it will torn down a "connected" route and, if there were other routes dependent on it (e.g. the default or whatever), they will be removed too. But since "the link is up" and "has Internet access" is not the same thing, it is possible that the eth is up (the carrier is present) but the device on the other side of the link it doesn't have access to Internet itself. (Imagine an Ethernet network like [device]--[switch]--[router]--...; physical layer ends on the switch, so even if router is failed, the device won't see it.) In this case Linux will happily see the link and keep the non-working route, so you shouldn't depend on this behaviour.
See here also.

Thank you very much for your answer! I expected this outcome, but hoped I was missing some popular solution for this kind of problems, maybe at least a 90% solution.
